# Multiple instances of Powerpoint

Tags: c#, vsto, add-in

I want to maintain different exes for each instance of the Powerpoint application.
On the web there is famous solution to invoke the power point using "run as" command which 
opens UAC dialog on windows 7 and RunAs dialog on XP machines.

Is there a way to suppress the login dialog in XP and the let the windows do its work in background as in Windows 7 so that user does not have to enter password when "run as" command is used.

I have a power point add-in. I am opening Powerpoint app from a c# application. I want my add-in to be available for only this instance of the power point. Unfortunately, there are no registry hacks to power point as there are for word & excel to instantiate multiple exes.

Comment: is this a programming question?

Comment: @AlexaAdrian yes its a programming question.

Comment: @AlexaAdrian hey I have developed a power point addin. I am instantiating power point from a c# application. I want to enable my addin to only this instance of power point. But the sad news is only one presentation can be seen at a time in windows. So I searched on the web, where I found this "run as" solution.